# Finding a ListView row in coded UI causes 'No row was specified as search container for the control.'

Tags: wpf, coded-ui-tests

I have a ListView inside of a Popup control (seems to be significant that it's in a Popup).  The coded test is pretty basic, click a ToggleButton to open the popup, and then select an item in the ListView.

Except it seems that it can't find the item in the ListView.

> System.ArgumentException: No row was specified as search container for
>   the control. To search for a cell control using 'ColumnIndex', you
>   must specify row as a container element or add 'RowIndex' to the
>   search property of the cell. Parameter name: SearchProperties Result
>   StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ALUtility.ThrowDataGridRelatedException(String
>   errorString, String propertyName)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls.WpfCell.GetUITestControlsForSearch()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.get_QueryId()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControlSearchArgument.get_SingleQueryString()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean
>   useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1
>   windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)

The generated code is failing at this point

```
uIItemCell.Checked = this.MyListBoxCellParams.UIItemCellChecked;
```

where uIItemCell comes from this property

```
    public WpfCell UIItemCell
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUIItemCell == null))
            {
                this.mUIItemCell = new WpfCell(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUIItemCell.SearchProperties[WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnHeader] = null;
                this.mUIItemCell.SearchProperties[WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex] = "1";
                this.mUIItemCell.WindowTitles.Add("CodedUITestWindow");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUIItemCell;
        }
    }
```

So I guess this is where the criteria should be specified, but what how?  And should row be hard coded somehow?  Why didn't the test editor set the row?

If it helps, this is the .ctor where UIItemCell (above) is specified, seems like more search params

```
    public UIMyCellDataItem(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        #region Search Criteria
        this.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "DataItem";
        this.SearchProperties["HelpText"] = "MyCell's helptext property, this is correctly specified, but the HelpText is used only as a tooltip";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("CodedUITestWindow");
        #endregion
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've normally seen ListView treated as a List, and the items as ListItem. You might want to use inspect.exe or the UI Test Builder to look at the properties.  You can try to manually code the control.  Sorry for posting speculation as an answer.  Too long to be a comment.

```
            WpfWindow PopUpWindow = new WpfWindow();
        PopUpWindow.SearchProperties[WpfWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Pop Up Window Name";

        WpfList List = new WpfList(PopUpWindow);
        List.SearchProperties[WpfList.PropertyNames.Name] = "List Name";

        WpfListItem ItemToSelect = new WpfListItem(List);
        ItemToSelect.SearchProperties[WpfListItem.PropertyNames.Name] = "List Item Name";

        // Click button to activate pop up window

        ItemToSelect.Select();


            // Creating the controls.
        WpfWindow mainWindow = new WpfWindow();
        // Add search properties.
        WpfTable table = new WpfTable(mainWindow);
        // Add search properties
        WpfRow row = new WpfRow(table);
        // Add search properties.
        WpfCell cell = new WpfCell(row);
        // Add search properties.

        // Just adding the table and row as containers.
        row.Container = table;
        cell.Container = row;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've narrowed it down right now to the fact that my list item is actually a grid with a label and a checkbox.  The code to select the item is                     this.mUIOnenameCell.SearchProperties[WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex] = "0";
                    this.mUIOnenameCell.SearchProperties[WpfCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex] = "0"; but it reports that "No table was specified as search container for the control. to search for a row or cell using ColumnIndex or RowIndex you must specify a table' - any idea how to specify a table?

Comment: You can pass the container in the constructor or use the container property.